# How can edit JavaScript file on chrome at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to edit the java Script file at Chrome runtime when debugging, but not able.I added breakpoint and at the time of debugging not able to edit it.

Comment: Probably you just have to reload page, because JSVM is running some earlier-saved cached scripts.

Comment: but i found a link https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/ that shows but tried and not worked

Comment: Any other browser provide this?

Comment: Ok, if you want to edit code that is on your hard drive, you have to [allow google chrome to use your workspace](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow), then you will be able to edit your code and save it.